# How To Download File In DWFX (AutoCad) Format In Rails Active Admin In Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Basically I am using gem 'activeadmin', github: 'Zhomart/active_admin', gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid', branch: 'mongoid-old' and gem 'mini_magick'. I am trying to download Map Image in Autocad Format Like: icon.dwfx , icon.dwg or icon.dxf file extension.I have no idea how i can achieved this in rails.
PDF Location: <%= form_tag "admin_form", method: :post do %> Latitude: <%= text_field_tag "lat", nil , placeholder: "Latitude" %> Longitude: <%= text_field_tag "long",nil, placeholder: "Longitude" %> <%= submit_tag "Submit" %> <% end %> function initMap() { var mapOptions = { zoom: 15, center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.5354383,77.26393259999998) }; var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions); var arr = $('#coordinates').data('url') var array = []; for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { var lat = arr[i][0] var lng = arr[i][1] array[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng) } markers = []; var flightPlanCoordinates = [ new google.maps.LatLng(28.5358,77.2764), new google.maps.LatLng(28.5223,77.2849), new google.maps.LatLng(28.5354383,77.26393259999998) ]; var polyline1 = new google.maps.Polyline({ path: array, strokeColor: '#FF0000', strokeOpacity: 1.0, strokeWeight: 2, }); var polyline2 = new google.maps.Polyline({ path: flightPlanCoordinates, strokeColor: '#FF0000', strokeOpacity: 1.0, strokeWeight: 2, }); for (var i = 0; i < polyline1.getPath().getLength(); i++) { var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: polyline1.getPath().getAt(i), title: polyline1.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6), map: map, draggable: true, label: "pole1", icon: { path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE, scale: 3 } }); marker.index = i; markers.push(marker); marker.setMap(map); google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function (event) { var val = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ?') if ( val == true) { polyline1.getPath().removeAt(this.index) this.setMap(null); markers.pop(marker); } else { return; } });

Comment: How's downloading a file is related to some gem(s)? Please explain what you're exactly trying to do with some efforts(code) for us to gain an idea as to how we can help you.

Comment: I am trying to download Google map  in .dwg format using Jquery.

Comment: Please post that jquery code